# Resize a DIV with multiple images on window resize

Tags: jquery, css, html, image-resizing, fluid

So I have 5 triangular images nested next to each other in a div. I simply just want the images to resize on window resize, or just keep somewhat of an aspect ratio on different resolutions. I currently have fixed widths but 100% open to alternative methods to get this working or even the proper way of doing it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="projects">

    <div id="project_1">
        <div id="snitch">   
            <img class="tribox1" src="" />
            <img class="tribox2" src="" />
            <img class="tribox3" src="" />
            <img class="tribox4" src="" />
            <img class="tribox5" src="" />  
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div id="project_2">
        <div id="snitch">   
            <img class="tribox1" src="" />
            <img class="tribox2" src="" />
            <img class="tribox3" src="" />
            <img class="tribox4" src="" />
            <img class="tribox5" src="" />  
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div id="project_3">
        <div id="snitch">   
            <img class="tribox1" src="" />
            <img class="tribox2" src="" />
            <img class="tribox3" src="" />
            <img class="tribox4" src="" />
            <img class="tribox5" src="" />  
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div id="project_4">
        <div id="snitch">   
            <img class="tribox1" src="" />
            <img class="tribox2" src="" />
            <img class="tribox3" src="" />
            <img class="tribox4" src="" />
            <img class="tribox5" src="" />  
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div id="project_5">
        <div id="snitch">   
            <img class="tribox1" src="" />
            <img class="tribox2" src="" />
            <img class="tribox3" src="" />
            <img class="tribox4" src="" />
            <img class="tribox5" src="" />  
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
    background-color: #1b1b1b;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    overflow: hidden ;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: left .2s ease;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width: 9800px;
}   

#projects {
    padding-top: 3.085%;
}   

#project_1, #project_2, #project_3, #project_4, #project_5 {
    float: left;    
}


#snitch {
    width: 1960px;
}

.tribox1 {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    background-position: bottom;
    padding-top: 5px;   
}

.tribox2 {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;   
    margin-left: -498px;    
}

.tribox3 {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    margin-left: -501px;    
}

.tribox4 {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;  
    margin-left: -500px;
}

.tribox5{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    background-position: bottom right;
    margin-left: -464px;
    padding-top: 51px;  
}
```

Comment: from next post onwards, please consider adding a jsfiddle too :)

http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/ETZkV/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your looking for a fluid layout and (dare I say) a 'responsive design' - set your container to width:100% and set your images to float:left, width:20%, height:auto;  If you have a maximum size for the container, set max-width on the container to that size.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize the images use following code..

```
 $(window).resize(function () {
    var h = parseInt($(window).height(), 10);
    var w = parseInt($(window).width(), 10);
    $("img").css({
        'width': w,
        'height': h
    });
});
```